# json data not showing in template view AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

So I've been trying to display the data from a json file in the template but for some reason, the data is not displaying.

Code from `app/js/controllers/controllers.js`

```
angular.module('myApp.views', ['ngRoute'])

.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('data/klanten.json')

    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.klanten = data;
        console.log($scope.klanten);
    });

    $scope.customer = {
        name: 'Naomi',
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre'    
    };

    //$scope.test = 9 * 5;

    //console.log($scope.klanten);

}).directive('myCustomer', ['$http', function($http) {
        //console.log($scope.klanten);
        return {
            template: 'Name: {{ klanten.voornaam }} Address: {{customer.address}}'
        };

}])
```

This is the code from the view template located in: `app/view/dashboard/dashboard.html`

```
<div class="container navbar-default">
        <nav role="navigation">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li><a href="#/views/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/views/profiel">Mijn profiel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/views/transacties">Mijn transacties</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Uitloggen</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

      </div>

<p>This is the partial for view 1.</p>

<p>{{ test }}</p>

<p>
    <div ng-controller="dashboardCtrl">
        <div my-customer></div>
    </div>
</p>
```

And this is how it looks in the front-end:

[image]

The $scope.customer is just test data. What I really want is to how the data from the json file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: '<p>{{ test }}</p>' should not be '<p>{{ klanten }}</p>'?

Comment: But shouldn't the data be coming through the directive??

Comment: Angular views and controllers share data throught scope object. So whenever you have attached 'klanten' on the scope, it is available on your view.

Comment: yes that's true except I thought I had to show the data through the directive instead. The directive shows the "Naomi" data without any fuss. Is not possible to show the data using the directive instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `{{test}}` in your `scope`. Try to write `{{klanten}}` in your view.

It should work.

You are using that kind of AngularJS request: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#shortcut-methods

Comment: You're getting the data from `data/klanten.json`. Is where you're requesting.

Comment: so the directive is not necessary in this case? Redundant?

Comment: If you wanna use the directive, has a little bit more complexity. In this case should be redundant, but you can used if you want. (not like this)

Comment: ok I'll accept the answer for now. If I need a directive in the future, I'll make a new question. Thanks a lot!